# Synaptics touchpad scroll doesn't work on many applications

Tags: windows-7, scrolling, synaptics-touchpad

The Synaptics touchpad in my new laptop doesn't scroll at all in a number of applications, including Steam and Zune.

I've narrowed the problem down to Synaptics not sending mouse wheel messages, but rather manipulating scroll bars.

I'm only looking into one-finger side-of-touchpad scrolling, not two-finger scrolling.

Is there a way to make it send wheel messages so that it is compatible with all applications?

Configuration:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Dell XPS 14
- Latest Synaptics driver
  (have tried both from Synaptics and
  Dell)

My Synaptics options window looks like this and I've tried moving all the options to no avail:

[image]

Comment: Your question is missing a crucial piece of information: your operating system.

Comment: Could you specify your model a bit more precisely?

Comment: It's this one: http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-14/pd

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After almost two years, I FINALLY found the solution!!

[As explained in this article](http://blog.alexou.net/2010/07/scrolling-in-gtk-apps-with-synaptics-driver/), it's as simple as editing the registry and adding a **DWORD** at **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPEnh** with name **UseScrollCursor** and value **0** and restarting SynTPEnh.exe.

This fixed the problem in Steam and Zune flawlessly, with both edge scrolling and two-finger scrolling.

Comment: I use this tip for few years with outdated Dell XPS 17 702x. Upgrade to Win 10 isn't supported, but I did. One of the problem with update is missing official Synaptic package from Dell (to get two fingers scroll). Recently I found that scroll icon displayed and the most annoying sometimes this icon stuck at screen and hide below view unless I killed `SynTPEnh.exe`. I found that Microsoft or Synaptic delivered new version of Synaptic package at 27Feb and registry tweak was removed, so I reapplied it again.

Answer (score 2):

There is a suggestion in this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/43966/vista-cant-touchpad-scroll-properly-in-apps-that-are-run-as-administrator/94544#94544) :

> The problem imho is not caused by the
>   driver, but it's the SynTPEnh.exe,
>   which is responsible for the scrolling
>   and other features (kill the process
>   in TaskManager, and two finger
>   scrolling won't work an more in any
>   application).
>
> If you manage to run this tool with
>   elevated privileges, two finger
>   scrolling should work even for
>   applications that were started as
>   administrator.
>
> One way to do this is to create a task
>   in the task scheduler, that will start
>   SynTPEnh.exe with highest privileges
>   at logon.

Question: Did you install drivers from Toshiba's website? Or did you let Windows 7 automatically install the drivers?

Comment: I don't want to disable scrolling, I just want it to work in all applications (it doesn't work in Steam, Zune or TortoiseHG, for example). I killed that process and it just disables it completely. Also, I want regular side-of-touchpad one-finger scrolling, not two-finger scrolling. My driver is the lastest one from Synaptic's site.

Comment: Did you try to restart it with "Run administrator" ?

Comment: The apps don't scroll not because they're run by administrator, they don't scroll because they have custom scrollbars that the Synaptics software can't manipulate. Sending regular mouse-wheel windows messages instead of manipulating scrollbars would fix this.

Comment: There is no "manipulation" of scrollbars in Windows. Devices such as the touchpad send scroll messages directly to the active window. However, some products in search of sexier scrollbars simply paint their own scrollbars and handle themselves all mouse clicks. Since as far as Windows is concerned these windows have no scrollbars, the touchpad messages will never even be sent. If that's your case, then there is no possible solution.

Comment: But Alps touchpads and normal mice scroll perfectly in these types of Windows...

Comment: @JulianaPena, not in all of them. He's refering to those which made their own thing altogether and implemented scrolling bad :)

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=74129) suggests going to Control Panel, then Mouse, then Device Settings until you see something like this:

[image: screenshot of Properties for Synaptics TouchPad]

Then, two things to try:

- Untick/uncheck `Enable virtual scrolling`
- Click the `[+]` to the left of `Virtual Scrolling` and change from "Scroll selected item" to "Scroll item under pointer"

If those options don't appear, can you post a screenshot of your settings?  Maybe there is an option to use a different scrolling mode or to exclude certain applications.

---

Otherwise, there is a program called [TwoFingerScroll](http://code.google.com/p/two-finger-scroll/) that sounds like it might help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my options window looks nothing like that (here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/YqVVY.png ) I don't have the "Virtual scrolling" option, just "Scrolling". Turning it off disables scrolling completely. I don't want two-finger scroll, just right edge one-finger scolling.

Comment: I tried the TwoFingerScroll program and it works! It send regular wheel messages and scrolls in all applications. If only there was a way to make one-finger side-of-touchpad scrolling work like that...

Comment: I'll give you the bounty because it's the only solution that sort-of worked. The TwoFingerScroll program scrolls in all apps, but it's not really the one-finger edge scrolling I was looking for.

Comment: Release notes for version 6.7.3.4: "Due to this change, "Scrolling selection" option on the touch pad Properties panel was removed." http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/6hgx31ww.txt -- does that explain the difference between Mikel's screenshot and Juliana's?

Comment: I just updated my driver from 15.0.18.0 to 15.1.19.0, and now I can scroll in some programs I couldn't scroll in before.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows 10 with edge, it was fixed by updating my synaptics driver.

This specific driver should work http://drivers.synaptics.com/Synaptics_v16_2_21_C_XP32_Vista32_Win7-32_XP64_Vista64_Win7-64_Win8.zip

Comment: That is just a driver download direct link... A better answer would have been something like "I had the same issue on Windows 10 with edge, it was fixed by updating my synaptics driver."

Answer (score 0):

I've used solution for synaptics driver 19x version Windows 7 SP1 x86 on my old Toshiba satellite a105 and it DOESNOT work.

Finally managed by installing Synaptic drivers 14x version and everything works as a champ. All newer 16, 17, 18 also doesn't work for me.